# Get all orders that contain a certain product

Tags: rules, commerce

I am trying to create a rule so that when a node containing a commerce product is update will notify all customers that have made a order containing this product.

I act on event "After updating existing content" and get to the commerce product using entity has field (field_product). 
How can I get from the product to all the orders containing it so I can loop through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a module for it as it didn't seem possible to implement using rules.

here is the function that is called on hook_node_update

```
//load all pending orders
$orders = commerce_order_load_multiple(array(), array('status'=>'pending'), TRUE);
//go through the loaded orders
foreach($orders as $order){
    //load each order as an entity
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
    foreach($order_wrapper->commerce_line_items as $line_item_wrapper){
        //check if the order contains this node's product
        $product = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product;
        $node_product = $node_wrapper->field_product;
        if($product->sku->value() === $node_product->sku->value()){
            //change the status of the order to processing  
            $order_wrapper->status = 'processing';
            $line_item_wrapper->save();

            $order_wrapper->save();
        }
    }
}
return TRUE;
```

Now since I got the respective orders to processing status, I can go on using rules for the rest of the implementation.